# Check if database entry exists Entity and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following repo code:

```
    public int Create(Address address)
    {
        context.Addresses.Add(address);

        int dbCity = context.Cities.Select(c => c.Name == address.City).Count();

        if( dbCity == 0 )
        {
            City newCity = new City
            {
                Name = address.City
            };
            context.Cities.Add(newCity);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();

        return address.AddressID;
    }
```

I want to say if there is a city found with the name `address.City` then don't make a new City in the database.. otherwise do.

- **Question** is, this syntax isn't good, what's the better way of doing that `.Count` bit...

Comment: Your model is not clear : `address.City` is a string representing city name, not a navigation property representing a City entity ?

Comment: what you mean by your 2nd question please explain it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do like this by using **Any()**:

```
 bool flag =  context.Cities.Any(c => c.Name == address.City);

    if(!flag)
    {
            // no city exists with this name
            City newCity = new City
            {
                Name = address.City
            };
    }
```

Comment: Ding din, you win. Thanks buddy!

Comment: They're just jealous brah. You got teh skillz! But it could be because you didn't answer question 2... but just for you i'll remove that one, because it seems it does.

Comment: i didn't understood your 2nd question, if your explain it i can answer you that as well...:)